# Need help in SMTP lib function

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

The function is being imported using the port number 547 and the gmail is open to less secure applications but while running I get a connection error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Code:

```
smtp_server='smtp.gmail.com'
port = 467
frm=input("Enter the sender's email address:   ")
toa=input("Enter the receiver's email address:   ")
msg="Here is a sample of the above converted csv file sent to the gmail"
pssw=input("Enter the password: ")
attach=('Airline_Record.csv')
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context):
    server.login(frm,pssw)
    server.sendmail(frm, toa, msg, attach)
    print('Mail sent')
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and not use ALL CAPS in title and text.

Comment: ohh sry just new to this

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP over SSL/TTL protocol was assigned the TCP port number 465. Not 467.

Comment: Thank yo for the answer but still no output

Comment: Please give more information. Is the TimeoutError solved? And what output did you expect? The guideline says: _"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error "_

Comment: i got it imported the mime stuff just like in the YouTube video       https://youtu.be/bXRYJEKjqIM

Comment: @SathyajithNishil That is a 20 minutes long video. I don't understand what is your question except the TimeoutError problem which I tried to answer. I will vote for closing this question as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

still no output.

```
   smtp_server='smtp.gmail.com'
   port = 465
   frm=input("Enter the sender's email address:   ")
   toa=input("Enter the receiver's email address:   ")
   msg="Here is a sample of the above converted csv file sent to the gmail"
   pssw=input("Enter the password: ")
   attach=('Airline_Record.csv')
   context = ssl.create_default_context()
        
   with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
       server.login(frm,pssw)
       server.sendmail(frm, toa, msg, attach)
       print('Mail sent')'
```